# Web Dev: Need Advice from a seasoned developer

Tags: django, git, web

Recently I've been getting into Django development and I am currently working on creating my own website. As for the static portions of the site, (about section, header, and footer) I am setting everything manually in my html file. Is this typically how professionals go about their business?

As for my github repository, I find my self having to create dozens of tedious commits as I troubleshoot (the site is hosted on AWS). Any advice on getting around redundancies in this aspect?

Comment: Checkout getbootstrap.com for first part of question if you are not using it.

Comment: @RagSagar Thanks Rag but I am using bootstrap and fine with the frontend portion of my site, just curious as to how dev's typically change static elements. Do people really go into the html everytime a description needs to be changed?

Comment: Are you using Django template inheritance?

Comment: @RagSagar yes I am